# How can I validate a TreeView using parsley.js?

Tags: asp.net, parsley.js

I'm using parsley for client-side validation and need to validate that a 3rd level node has been selected.

I have tried just adding the required="" attribute to the treeview tag but this doesn't appear to work.

It appears that parsley just ignores the TreeView control.

Are there any custom validators that address TreeViews?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No custom validators that I know of. You'll have to write your own.